# Swift get stripe charge id when payment has succeeded

Tags: ios, swift, stripe-payments, swift5

I am using stripe api to make a payment.

I am trying to receive the charge ID from the pay() function but do not see the charge id in any of the Param Variables. Is this something I have to do server side? I would assume the charge id would be in the payment intent params but it is not. Do I have to fetch the charge id some other way?

**charge id example:**

> "id": "ch_1IXpNqHiSsWQPbMQ3dNTp73m"

I create a payment intent server side and process the payment like so: https://stripe.com/docs/payments/integration-builder

```
@objc
  func pay() {
    guard let paymentIntentClientSecret = paymentIntentClientSecret else {
        return;
    }
    // Collect card details
    let cardParams = cardTextField.cardParams
    let paymentMethodParams = STPPaymentMethodParams(card: cardParams, billingDetails: nil, metadata: nil)
    let paymentIntentParams = STPPaymentIntentParams(clientSecret: paymentIntentClientSecret)
    paymentIntentParams.paymentMethodParams = paymentMethodParams
    // Submit the payment
    let paymentHandler = STPPaymentHandler.shared()
    paymentHandler.confirmPayment(withParams: paymentIntentParams, authenticationContext: self) { (status, paymentIntent, error) in
      switch (status) {
      case .failed:
          self.displayAlert(title: "Payment failed", message: error?.localizedDescription ?? "")
          break
      case .canceled:
          self.displayAlert(title: "Payment canceled", message: error?.localizedDescription ?? "")
          break
      case .succeeded:
          self.displayAlert(title: "Payment succeeded", message: paymentIntent?.description ?? "")
          break
      @unknown default:
          fatalError()
          break
      }
    }
  }
```

**Param output:**

succeeded:

> nil

status:

> STPPaymentHandlerActionStatus

paymentIntent:

> Optional(<Stripe.STPPaymentIntent: 0x600003d443c0; stripeId =
> pi_xxx; amount = 555; canceledAt = nil;
> captureMethod = Optional("automatic"); clientSecret = ;
> confirmationMethod = Optional("automatic"); created = 2021-03-22
> 15:08:09 +0000; currency = usd; description = nil; lastPaymentError =
> nil; livemode = false; nextAction = nil; paymentMethodId =
> Optional("pm_1IXpMTKn7R1M6tqnP8vs3i7n"); paymentMethod =
> Optional(<Stripe.STPPaymentMethod: 0x600003d445a0; stripeId =
> pm_1IXpMTKn7R1M6tqnP8vs3i7n; alipay = nil; auBECSDebit = nil;
> bacsDebit = nil; bancontact = nil; billingDetails =
> Optional(<Stripe.STPPaymentMethodBillingDetails: 0x600002106d00; name
> = ; phone = ; email = ; address = Optional(<Stripe.STPPaymentMethodAddress: 0x600002c02b80; line1 = ;
> line2 = ; city = ; state = ; postalCode = ; country = >)>); card =
> Optional(<Stripe.STPPaymentMethodCard: 0x600003015320; brand = Visa;
> checks = <Stripe.STPPaymentMethodCardChecks: 0x600000dc4090;
> addressLine1Check: ; addressPostalCodeCheck: ; cvcCheck: >; country =
> US; expMonth = 4; expYear = 2024; funding = credit; last4 = 4242;
> fingerprint = ; networks = <Stripe.STPPaymentMethodCardNetworks:
> 0x600000dc4060; available: ["visa"]; preferred: >; threeDSecureUsage =
> <Stripe.STPPaymentMethodThreeDSecureUsage: 0x6000002a0200; supported:
> YES>; wallet = >); cardPresent = nil; created = Optional(2021-03-22
> 15:08:10 +0000); customerId = ; ideal = nil; eps = nil; fpx = nil;
> giropay = nil; netBanking = nil; oxxo = nil; grabPay = nil; payPal =
> nil; przelewy24 = nil; sepaDebit = nil; sofort = nil; upi = nil;
> afterpay_clearpay = nil; liveMode = NO; type = card>);
> paymentMethodTypes = Optional(["card"]); receiptEmail = nil;
> setupFutureUsage = nil; shipping = nil; sourceId = nil; status =
> Optional("succeeded")>)

paymentIntentParams:

> <Stripe.STPPaymentIntentParams: 0x600003544000; stripeId =
> Optional("pi_1IXpMTKn7R1M6tqn8WIzEoyE"); clientSecret = ;
> receiptEmail = nil; returnURL = nil; savePaymentMethod = nil;
> setupFutureUsage = nil; shipping = nil; useStripeSDK = nil; sourceId =
> nil; sourceParams = nil; paymentMethodId = nil; paymentMethodParams =
> Optional(<Stripe.STPPaymentMethodParams: 0x60000377ee80>); mandateData
> = nil; paymentMethodOptions = @nil; additionalAPIParameters = [:]> card params:  <Stripe.STPPaymentMethodCardParams: 0x600002163ca0;
> last4 = 4242; expMonth = 4; expYear = 24; cvc = ; token = >

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A PaymentIntent has all its Charges under the `charges` list [0] but that is only returned server-side, it is not currently retrievable via a Publishable key.

You would fetch the PaymentIntent server-side which will return you the entire `charges` list, with the most recent Charge being the first element in that list.

[0] https://stripe.com/docs/api/payment_intents/object#payment_intent_object-charges

Comment: So your saying I have to fetch the payment intent twice? Once before the charge and once after the charge to get the charge id?

Comment: You "create" the PaymentIntent first, so you aren't technically fetching it, but yes your mobile app talks to your server to first get a PaymentIntent `client_secret`. Then in your `confirmCardPayment()` completion block, your app talks to your server again to obtain the Charge ID for that PaymentIntent. Alternatively, you can just share the PaymentIntent ID with your customer, assuming the PaymentIntent `status: succeeded` as it is in your example above

Comment: So retrieve the PaymentIntent by sending the payment intent id to server side. Which will then give me a list of the charge ids, the first charge being the most recent?

Comment: I feel this method is a security risk sending the payment intent id. There has to be a way around this using STPPaymentContext or STPPaymentResult

Comment: " the first charge being the most recent?" -> YES. "I feel this method is a security risk sending the payment intent id" -> it is not a security risk, it is just a PaymentIntent ID just like a Charge ID is an ID. For anyone to do anything material with it (say refund the payment), they need access to your secret API key, which is private and lives on your backend. There is no issue sharing a PaymentIntent ID or Charge ID with a customer. They have access to it anyways if they use a network inspector and see what requests your mobile app is making, this is expected and a non issue.

Comment: There doesn't seem to be any Charges on the PaymentIntents object anymore? The [0] link goes to the top of the page, and reading  https://stripe.com/docs/api/payment_intents/object shows no Charges anywhere?

Comment: Turns out they ditched charges[] in favor of latest_charge as of 2022-11-15, see https://github.com/stripe/stripe-ruby/issues/927#issuecomment-1353522284 - Stripe sure is no longer simple... ;)